Python iterparse for all files - big and small
I have used ElementTree.parse() to parse all xml files. This failed when the xml file was 950 MB. So, I switched to ElementTree.iterparse() which works like a charm.
My question is, should I use ElementTree.iterparse() for files of all sizes ? Or, may be, put a check on the file size.
If file size is less than X MB, use ElementTree.parse(), else use ElementTree.iterparse()).
It would be nice to use one function that does everything. But, will do what is right for the use case.
Thank you.
